# Python getting an error while sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, lambda

Didn't use Python in a while..having some problems while sorting a dictionary

i have a dictionary called `bad_functions` holding ~500 pairs

example : `{'lambda_1': 0, 'lambda_2': 0,, 'lambda_2': "unreserved}`

code :

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import subprocess
import json

# deafult region is us-east-2
region="us-east-2"

# command for getting all lambdas lambdas in eu-east-2 
list_lambda_command = "aws lambda list-functions --region {region} --query 'Functions[].FunctionName' --output json"
# command for getting a specific lambda cuoncurrency  
lambda_concurrency="aws lambda get-function-concurrency --function-name {function_name}"

# running the first aws cli command on host and load to list object 
lambda_json_output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', list_lambda_command.format(region=region)]).decode()
lambda_list=json.loads(lambda_json_output)

# empty list for incoming 'bad' lambda's results
bad_functions={}

for function in lambda_list: 
    # getting lambda funcations with unreserved concurreny value into a dict
    try:
        output=subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', lambda_concurrency.format(function_name=function)]).decode()
        current_lambda_concurrency=json.loads(output)
    except:
        bad_functions[f'{function}']="unreserved"
        continue

    # getting lambda funcations with 'bad' concurreny value value into a dict
    current_concurrency=current_lambda_concurrency['ReservedConcurrentExecutions']
    if current_concurrency != 1:
        bad_functions[f'{function}']=int(current_concurrency)

# sorting the dic by value
print(bad_functions)
bad_functions_sorted={k: v for k, v in sorted(bad_functions.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

**ERROR i get :**

```
File "script.py", line 40, in <module>
    bad_functions_sorted={k: v for k, v in sorted(bad_functions.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: The example provided does not generated the error provided. Please provide a proper example so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Suggestion: replace `key=lambda item: item[1]` with `key=lambda item: str(item[1])`. But I can't guarantee that this will sort in the order that you want.

Comment: hmm i understand Capie,but the dict info is kinda private.how should i give such exaple ?

Comment: updated my post to use the whole code..i hope its easier to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,didnt give enough information in the question.

A possible output could've been

```
{'lambda_1': 0, 'lambda_2': 0,, 'lambda_2': "unreserved}
```

So the ERROR `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` makes a lot of sense

What i did to solve this is to separate them to 2 different dicts

```
for function in lambda_list: 

    try:
        output=subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', lambda_concurrency.format(function_name=function)]).decode()
        current_lambda_concurrency=json.loads(output)
    except:
        unreserved_function[f'{function}']="unreserved"
        continue

  current_concurrency=current_lambda_concurrency['ReservedConcurrentExecutions']
    if current_concurrency != 1:
        concurrency_functions[f'{function}']=int(current_concurrency)
```

And only sorted the 'int' dict

```
bad_functions_sorted={k: v for k, v in sorted(concurrency_functions.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```